# Morphism of $k$-algebras between matrix rings over $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

> Let $k$ be a field and $f:M_n(k) \to M_m(k)$ be a morphism of $k$-algebras ($n,m \in \mathbb N$). Prove that $n$ divides $m$.

I have no idea what to do here. I thought that maybe I should take an appropriate block matrix in $M_n(k)$ and use the fact that $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$ but I suppose I have to use the fact that $f(kA)=kf(A)$ as well. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Consider the $M_m(k)$ module $k^m$. Any $M_m(k)$ module is a direct sum of copies of $k^m$.

The same is true for $M_n(k)$ and $k^n$.

Under the morphism $M_n(k) \to M_m(k)$ $\ \ k^m$ becomes an $M_n(k)$ module. Hence it's a sum of copies of $k^n$. Now take $\dim_k$.

Comment: It's funny that a complete proof is entitled as a Hint.

Comment: @orangeskid sorry to ask you like two months later, I understand your solution except for one thing, why "Any $M_m(k)$ module is a direct sum of copies of $k^m$"?

Comment: A very good question! Let's check two things: $k^n$ is a simple $M_n(k)$ module ( since for any $v \ne 0$ and $w$ in $k^n$ some element in $M_n(k)$ takes $v$ to $w$. Second: $M_n(k)$ is a direct sum of submodules isomorphic to $k^n$ (one  distinguished column $\ne 0$ ...). From here it follows that any $M_n(k)$ module is a direct sum of $k^n$ ( perhaps for us enough the ones that are finite dimensional spaces over $k$). That requires some proof indeed, once you see it it's not that difficult to understand.

Comment: Do a search for "semisimple module".